# How to add attachment based on condition using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to attach a file to an email.

The date of the file will change according to the day.

If `strlocation` is present it should be attached else `strlocation1` should be attached.

```vb
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strLocation1 As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Signature = OutMail.body
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hello," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "some text." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "some text," & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    strLocation = "file location" & Format(Now() - 3, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsx"
    strLocation1 = "file location " & Format(Now() - 1, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsx"
    '.Attachments.Add (strLocation) 
    'Or .Attachments.Add(strLocation1)
```

Comment: Today, strLocation1 has value 'file location05.25.18.xlsx' is this really you want to?

Comment: I was trying to save the file in different dates according to the day I am running the Macro. If it is Monday, I want to save the file in a date that is 3 days prior to today's date and in other days, I'll save the file with the date as previous day. I was trying to attach the file if monday file present else attach the other day's file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for trying. I found it by myself. Here is the code that will do my requirement.

```
    If strLocation1 = "" Then
        .Attachments.Add (strLocation1)
    Else
        .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
    End If
```